# TargetParameterCountException when enumerating through properties of string

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I'm using the following code to output values of properties:

```cs
string output = String.Empty;
string stringy = "stringy";
int inty = 4;
Foo spong = new Foo() {Name = "spong", NumberOfHams = 8};
foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in stringy.GetType().GetProperties())
{
  if (propertyInfo.CanRead) output += propertyInfo.GetValue(stringy, null);
}
```

If I run this code for the `int`, or for the `Foo` complex type, it works fine. But if I run it for the `string` (as shown), I get the following error on the line inside the `foreach` loop:

> ```txt
> System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException: Parameter count mismatch.
> ```

Does anyone know what this means and how to avoid it?

In case anyone asks 'why are you enumerating through the properties of a string', eventually I hope to create a generic class which will output the properties of any type passed to it (which might be a string...).

Comment: Perhaps it would be more helpful to ask how to create a reflection-based property value enumerator?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In this case, one of the string's properties is the indexer for returning the character at the specified location. Thus, when you try to `GetValue`, the method expects an index but doesn't receive one, causing the exception.

To check which properties require index you can call `GetIndexParameters` on the `PropertyInfo` object. It returns an array of `ParameterInfo`, but you can just check the length of that array (if there are no parameters, it will be zero)

Comment: Thank you. How can I detect and avoid index-based properties?

Comment: Call GetIndexParameters on the PropertyInfo object. It returns an array of ParameterInfo, but you can just check the length of that array (if there are no parameters, it will be zero)

Answer (score 5):

`System.String` has an indexed property that returns the `char` in the specified location. An indexed property needs an argument (index in this case) therefore the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Just as reference... if you want to avoid the TargetParameterCountException when reading properties values:

```
// Ask each childs to notify also, if any could (if possible)
foreach (PropertyInfo prop in options.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    if (prop.CanRead) // Does the property has a "Get" accessor
    {
        if (prop.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0) // Ensure that the property does not requires any parameter
        {
            var notify = prop.GetValue(options) as INotifyPropertyChanged; 
            if (notify != null)
            {
                notify.PropertyChanged += options.OptionsBasePropertyChanged;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Will get TargetParameterCountException if query:
            // var notify = prop.GetValue(options) as INotifyPropertyChanged;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps ;-)