# How to bind complex properties within polymorphic model in Asp.Net MVC 4?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, model-binding, custom-model-binder

I need to create a dynamic input form based on a derived type but I cannot get complex properties bound properly when passed to the POST method of my controller.  Other properties bind fine.  Here is a contrived example of what I have:

**Model**

```
public abstract class ModelBase {}

public class ModelDerivedA : ModelBase
{       
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }       
    public SomeType MySomeType{ get; set; }

    public ModelDerivedA()
    {
        MySomeType = new SomeType();
    }
}

public class SomeType 
{             
    public string SomeTypeStringA { get; set; }
    public string SomeTypeStringB { get; set; }         
}
```

**Custom Model Binder**

The binder is based on this answer: [polymorphic-model-binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222533/polymorphic-model-binding)

```
public class BaseViewModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    protected override object CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType)
    {
        var typeValue = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("ModelType");
        var type = Type.GetType(
            (string)typeValue.ConvertTo(typeof(string)),
            true
        );
        if (!typeof(ModelBase).IsAssignableFrom(type))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The model does not inherit from mode base");
        }
        var model = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        bindingContext.ModelMetadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(() => model, type);
        return model;
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult    GetDynamicForm([ModelBinder(typeof(BaseViewModelBinder))] ModelBase model)
{
   // model HAS values for SomeProperty 
   // model has NO values for MySomeType
}
```

**View Excerpt**

```
@Html.Hidden("ModelType", Model.GetType())
@Html.Test(Model);
```

**JavaScript**

The form is posted using `$.ajax` using `data: $(this).serialize()`, which, if I debug shows the correct populated form data.

All properties are populated in the model excluding those of `SomeType`.  What do I need to change to get them populated?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my immediate issue by:

1. get an instance of `FormvalueProvider` (to get access to what has been posted)
2. recursively going through my model and setting each property value to the matching value in the `FormValueProvider`

   ```
   private FormValueProvider vp;

   protected override object CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType)
   {
       var typeValue = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("ModelType");

       var type = Type.GetType(
           (string)typeValue.ConvertTo(typeof(string)),
           true
       );
       if (!typeof(ModelBase).IsAssignableFrom(type))
       {
           throw new InvalidOperationException("Bad Type");
       }

       var model = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

       vp = new FormValueProvider(controllerContext);

       bindingContext.ValueProvider = vp;
       SetModelPropertValues(model);

       return model;        
   }
   ```

And the recursion, based on this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20554103/recursively-get-properties-child-properties-of-a-class) to print properties in nested objects

```
    private void SetModelPropertValues(object obj)
    {
        Type objType = obj.GetType();
        PropertyInfo[] properties = objType.GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            object propValue = property.GetValue(obj, null);
            var elems = propValue as IList;
            if (elems != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in elems)
                {
                    this.SetModelPropertValues(item);
                }
            }
            else
            {                   
                if (property.PropertyType.Assembly == objType.Assembly)
                {                        
                    this.SetModelPropertValues(propValue);
                }
                else
                {
                  property.SetValue(obj, this.vp.GetValue(property.Name).AttemptedValue, null);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Anyone using this may need to make it more robust for their needs.

I would be very intersted to hear of any drawbacks to this as a general approach to this kind of problem.

However, I'm hoping that this post helps in some situations.

Answer (score 1):

Values are not being populated because you are creating new instance of type like following:

```
var model = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
bindingContext.ModelMetadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(() => model, type);
return model;
```

and returning the same model instead which is not correct.

do something like below.

```
ValueProviderResult valueResult;
bindingContext.ModelState.SetModelValue("ModelType", valueResult);       
return valueResult;
```

Here is very good discussion on modelBinder.

http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2009/05/05/iterating-on-an-asp-net-mvc-model-binder.aspx

Comment: thanks @Jenish but wouldn't all the properties be empty then (not just the complex property)?

Comment: yes, I couldn't get this to work but I haven't spent a lot of time on it today.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add default constructor to your `ModelDerivedA` to initialize `MySomeType`

```
public class ModelDerivedA : ModelBase
{
    public ModelDerivedA()
    {
        MySomeType = new SomeType();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean, please explain? This constuctor should create an instance of the `SomeType`.

Comment: But will it solve the problem by populating the form field inside?

Comment: @Max, thanks, this is an issue in my example, when fixed it does not fix the binding issue.

Comment: @davy it does not fix binding issue.