# How to determine if all properties of type List<T> in an object are null or empty?

Tags: c#

I have an object which contains few int/string properties and some List<T> properties where T are some other classes in the project itself. Is there a cleaner way to determine if only those List<T> properties are empty or null? Maybe using a Linq statement?

I tried searching about it but can't find a short and clean way. Should i opt for reflection?? Can someone provide a sample related to this?

```
public class A
{
   ..some properties..
   List<ClassA> ListA { get; set; }
   List<ClassB> ListB { get; set; }
   List<ClassC> ListC { get; set; }
   List<ClassD> ListD { get; set; }
   ..some properties..
}
```

EDIT 1:
So far i have managed to write a clean code to check if list properties are null. But how can i check if they are empty. I need to convert object to List but i dont know the type of List it is

```
var matchFound = myObject.GetType().GetProperties()
                        .Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(List<>))
                        .Select(x => x.GetValue(myObject))
                        .Any(x => x != null);
```

EDIT 2:
I ended up using this, a one liner that works fine:

```
var matchFound = myObject.GetType().GetProperties()
                        .Where(x =>(x.GetValue(myObject) as IList)?.Count()>0);
```

Comment: It should be possible with the [List<T>.TrueForAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.trueforall?view=netcore-2.2) method.

Comment: my requirement is that i have an object of the above stated class. there are many lists so i dont want to check them individually if ListA is empty or not then ListB is empty or not and so on....is it achieveable by linq or reflection??

Comment: try to consider the recursive traversing all properties using reflection - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20554103/recursively-get-properties-child-properties-of-a-class

Comment: @ChrisRollins: I can't see how `TrueForAll` would be useful here - the lists themselves are only being checked for being empty (or a null reference). That doesn't require examining any *elements* of the list.

Comment: If you don't know the generic type, but you know the property name, it might be easier and faster to just use `myObject.ListA?.Cast<object>().Any() == true`. Repeat for all the properties of type 'List<T>'. You could use reflection to do this (or expression trees), but using reflection is far slower than just casting to object

Comment: sadly i dont know the property names too...trying to write something totally generic...but your option seems promising

Comment: Note that `.Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(List<>))` will never find any properties. A property wouldn't be of type `List<>`, because that's the open generic type. You'd need to detect that the property is of a type which is a type constructed from `List<>`.

Comment: So you want to do this for any class that might have any number of properties of `List<TypeInYourAssembly>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what i would do.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// caching a Dyctionary of IList types for faster browsing
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="type"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static readonly Dictionary<Type, Type> CachedActualType = new Dictionary<Type, Type>();
    // Get Internal type of IList.
    // When the type is not a list then it will return the same type.
    // if type is List<T> it will return the type of T
    public static Type GetActualType(this Type type)
    {
        if (CachedActualType.ContainsKey(type))
            return CachedActualType[type];

        if (type.GetTypeInfo().IsArray)
            CachedActualType.Add(type, type.GetElementType());
        else if (type.GenericTypeArguments.Any())
            CachedActualType.Add(type, type.GenericTypeArguments.First());// this is almost always find the right type of an IList but if it fail then do the below. dont really remember why this fail sometimes.
        else if (type.FullName?.Contains("List`1") ?? false)
            CachedActualType.Add(type, type.GetRuntimeProperty("Item").PropertyType);
        else
            CachedActualType.Add(type, type);

        return CachedActualType[type];
    }
```

And then

```
var matchFound = myObject.GetType().GetProperties()
                        .Where(x => x.PropertyType.GetActualType() != x.PropertyType && 
                              (x.GetValue(myObject) as IList)?.Count()>0);
```

You can actually do even better and dont need to check for type and only try to cast the value.
The value will always be null if the type is not an IList

```
var matchFound = myObject.GetType().GetProperties()
                        .Where(x =>(x.GetValue(myObject) as IList)?.Count()>0);
```

Comment: OMG how could I miss that... yeah I could just simply cast in where clause...it works, its fast and it's clean to maintain...thanks..!!

Comment: Glad i could help :)

Answer (score 0):

You need quite a bit of reflection:

```cs
// the type to test
public class TestData
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public List<string> B { get; set; }
    public List<int> C { get; set; }
}

// an helper class used to generate checking functions
public static class ListTester
{
    public static Func<T, bool> MakeClassChecker<T>()
        where T : class
    {
        var checkFunctions = EnumerateListProperties<T>()
            .Select(MakePropertyChecker<T>)
            .ToList();

        return instance => checkFunctions.All(f => f(instance));
    }

    public static IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> EnumerateListProperties<T>()
    {
        return typeof(T).GetProperties(Instance | Public | NonPublic)
            .Where(prop => IsListClosedType(prop.PropertyType));
    }

    public static Func<T, bool> MakePropertyChecker<T>(PropertyInfo prop)
        where T : class
    {
        var propType = prop.PropertyType;
        var listItemType = propType.GenericTypeArguments[0];

        var listEmptyChecker = (Func<object, bool>) ListCheckerFactoryMethod
            .MakeGenericMethod(listItemType).Invoke(null, new object[0]);

        return instance => instance != null && listEmptyChecker(prop.GetValue(instance));
    }

    private static MethodInfo ListCheckerFactoryMethod
        = typeof(ListTester).GetMethod(nameof(ListCheckerFactory), Static | Public);


    public static Func<object, bool> ListCheckerFactory<T>()
    {
        return list => list == null || ((List<T>) list).Count == 0;
    }

    public static bool IsListClosedType(Type type)
    {
        return type != null &&
                type.IsConstructedGenericType &&
                type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>);
    }
}

[Test]
public void TestTemp()
{
    var props = ListTester.EnumerateListProperties<TestData>();
    CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(props.Select(prop => prop.Name), new[] {"B", "C"});

    var allListsAreNullOrEmpty = ListTester.MakeClassChecker<TestData>();

    Assert.That(allListsAreNullOrEmpty(new TestData()), Is.True);
    Assert.That(allListsAreNullOrEmpty(new TestData() {B = new List<string>()}), Is.True);
    Assert.That(allListsAreNullOrEmpty(new TestData() {B = new List<string>() {"A"}}), Is.False);
}
```

Now, for the important bits: you search for properties of *closed* generic types of `List<>`.
The selection of the properties is done in `IsListClosedType`.
Then, for each property, we make a checking function using `MakePropertyChecker`.

The job of `MakePropertyChecker` is to build via `MakeGenericMethod` a version of `ListCheckerFactory`
of the appropriate type.

Answer (score 0):

You want to check all properites that are of type `List<something>`
This method can do the trick:

```
bool IsGenericList(Type t)
{
    return t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>);
}
```

Now you can modify your Linq query so it returns if at least one of List members is not null or empty

```
var matchFound = myObject.GetType().GetProperties()
    .Where(p => IsGenericList(p.PropertyType))
    .Select(p => p.GetValue(myObject) as IEnumerable)
    .Any(list => list != null && list.Cast<object>().Any());//Cast<object> needed to be able to use Linq Any()
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use reflection for your requirement, i have just tried it.

```
       class Test
       {

       }
        class UserDetails
        {
            public List<Test> Test1 { get; set; }
            public List<Test> Test2 { get; set; }
            public string firstname { get; set; }
            public string surname { get; set; }
            public string city { get; set; }
            public string state { get; set; }
        }
```

Use this query to search, you can customize where condition for your requirement

```
UserDetails yourObject = new UserDetails();
            yourObject.Test1 = new List<Test> { new Test() };

            var result = typeof(UserDetails).GetProperties()
                .Select(prop => prop)
                .Where(property =>
                {
                    if (property.PropertyType == typeof(List<Test>))
                    {
                        var value = (List<Test>)property.GetValue(yourObject, null);
                        return value == null || value.Count == 0;
                    }

                    return false;
                }).ToList(); // this will return 1 because 1 property has count > 1
```

Update if use Templete

```
class UserDetails<T>
    {
        public List<T> Test1 { get; set; }
        public List<T> Test2 { get; set; }
        public string firstname { get; set; }
        public string surname { get; set; }
        public string city { get; set; }
        public string state { get; set; }
    }
```

Query

```
UserDetails<Test> yourObject = new UserDetails<Test>();
            yourObject.Test1 = new List<Test> { new Test() };

            var result = typeof(UserDetails<Test>).GetProperties()
                .Select(prop => prop)
                .Where(property =>
                {
                    if (property.PropertyType == typeof(List<Test>))
                    {
                        var value = (List<Test>)property.GetValue(yourObject, null);
                        return value == null || value.Count == 0;
                    }

                    return false;
                }).ToList();
```

Comment: i already did this but i have a problem. if i refer to your code the class Test is not known to me...it can be any class hence the question

Comment: you can change to your class ClassA, ClassB it is same

Comment: as i already told....these classes are not known to me in the object...there is no definite list..

Comment: Can you post your class to question

Comment: i can't...terms & conditions