# Using reflection to cast an object to List of custom type

Tags: c#, list, generics, reflection, casting

I have following scenario:

I have compound object which includes lists in it, I want to pass a 'path' to it like - Result.CustomerList.Name

Result is an object that contains List of Customer, but also contains many other lists of different types. I want to get to the Names of the customers in this particular case.

What I have so far

```
    private static object GetPropertyValue(this object obj, string propertyPath)
    {
        var fullPath = propertyPath.Split('.');
        for (int i = 0; i <= fullPath.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (obj == null) { return null; }
            var part = fullPath[i];

            Type type = obj.GetType();
            PropertyInfo propInfo = type.GetProperty(part);

            if (propInfo == null)
            {
                //if its a list
                if (obj.GetType().GetInterfaces().Any(
                    k => k.IsGenericType
                    && k.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>)))
                {
                    //get list generic argument
                    var argumentType = obj.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];

                   //cast obj to List of argumentType


                }
                else return null;
            }

            obj = propInfo.GetValue(obj, null);
        }

        return obj;
    }
```

I cant get the syntax or how to cast to List or List it doesnt work or List

I dont understand what i have missing or how to do it.

EDIT::
During runtime might be CustomerList, AddressList or PaymentList or any other type of list. I need a method to be able to retrieve the property value within any type of list during runtime.

EDIT2::
Example of Result object

```
public class SearchResults
{
    public List<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public List<Payment> Payments { get; set; }
    public List<Address> Addresses{ get; set; }
    public int totalCount { get; set; }
    public bool success { get; set; }


}

public class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long Id { get; set; }
}

public class Payment
{
    public string BankName{ get; set; }
    public long Id { get; set; }
}
```

So a path like Result.Payments.BankName  should return me whatever. Problem is that I cant make it generic for the method to access any of the lists.

Comment: The most obvious is that you cannot cast at runtime, as casting is a compile-time thing. You allways end up with some un-specific `object`.

Comment: This might by a XY problem. What exactly do you want to do? Ignoring the reflection stuff.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just pass the List property?  What pass the object and a string path?

Comment: if `CustomerList` in `Result.CustomerList.Name` is a collection, wouldn´t you need an index of a single item? Something like `Result.CustomerList[index].Name`?

Comment: @Neijwiert i want to be able to get any value within any object. I have object with customer data with payment data and etc, i want to be able to get the value of any property within given class - Result.CustomerData.Name; Result.Payments.BankId and so on, I need to be able to handle any type of lists during runtime, do not want to hardcode specific types

Comment: @HimBromBeere during runtime i dont know if its going to be CustomerList or PaymentList or AddressList all i know its a list and i need to be able to loop through it

Comment: Yeah, but `myList.Name` simply makes no sense. A list does not have a `Name`.

Comment: Anyway you should use some recursive method in order to access the nested elements. Look this for inspiration: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20554103/recursively-get-properties-child-properties-of-a-class

Comment: `Result.Customers.Where(c => c.Id == 12345).Name`  You're making a massive deal out of something very simple.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be easier to just enumerate the object, by casting it to an IEnumerable:

```
var objCollection = obj as IEnumerable;
if (objCollection == null)
{
    // this is not a collection
}
else
{
    // just enumerate the objCollection.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my problem with dynamic

```
private static object GetPropertyValue(this object obj, string propertyPath)
    {
        var fullPath = propertyPath.Split('.');
        for(int i = 0; i <= fullPath.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (obj == null) { return null; }
            var part = fullPath[i];

            Type type = obj.GetType();
            PropertyInfo propInfo = type.GetProperty(part);

            if (propInfo == null)
            {
                //if its a list
                if (obj.GetType().GetInterfaces().Any(
                    k => k.IsGenericType
                    && k.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>)))
                {
                    //convert to IList from object
                    var genericList = (IList)obj;

                    //returned the desired property
                    return genericList.Cast<dynamic>()
                        .First(p => p.PropertyName.ToLower().Equals(part.ToLower()))
                        .PropertyValue;
                }
                else return null;
            }

            obj = propInfo.GetValue(obj, null);
        }

        return obj;
    }
```

This method now works for each list in my object.